# Loading text into R and transform it to a list

Tags: r, list

I have a text file and the content is:

```
Oliver is happy
Oliver is sad
Oliver is angry
Oliver is feeling ecstatic
```

I am trying to load this to R so that I can have a list variable and each item on the list would contain a sentence.  For example, in a list called 'mood', the first item would be 'Oliver is happy' and second item would be 'Oliver is sad'.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reading file in R, where `file` is your table that I copied:

```
df <- read.table(file = "clipboard", header = F, sep = "\t")
```

creating a list:

```
mood <- as.character(unlist(df))

> mood
[1] "Oliver is happy"            "Oliver is sad"              "Oliver is angry"           
[4] "Oliver is feeling ecstatic"
```